# Finitely generated solvable subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Q})$ has finite Prufer rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am thinking of using the Lie–Kolchin triangularization theorem, which says the image group $\rho(G)$  for $G$, a solvable linear group, is conjugate to a subgroup of the upper triangular matrices.

The Prufer rank is defined to be $\operatorname{sr}(G)=\max_{H \leq G} \min\{ |X|: X \subseteq H, \langle X \rangle = H \}$.

Would this work?

Comment: Lie-Kolchin only is true over an algebraically closed field. A proof of your title claim is given in Proposition $2.3$ [here](http://www.maths.nuigalway.ie/~dane/YJABR14338.pdf).